# VITE: "Failed too load url" for vue single file component

Tags: vue.js, vite

I have a VUE application that's bundled with vite. I have a problem when loading dependencies as vue single file components. Everything is according to the standard scaffolded vite example.

Here is my `vite.config.js`

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      // This SHOULD resolve my imports, but it seems to have a problem
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))    
    }
  }
})
```

Here is my vue `router.js` file that tries to import a dependancy

```
import welcomeChat from "@/views/welcome-chat"   //<======= this throws an error

const router = createRouter({
 history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    {
        path: "/welcome",
        name: "welcome",
        component: welcomeChat
    }
})
```

`npm run dev` works, but then when I open my app in the browser I get the following **error**

```
Failed to load url /src/views/welcome-chat (resolved id: /Users/doogie/Coding/liquido/liquido-mobile-pwa-vue3_3/src/views/welcome-chat) in /Users/doogie/Coding/liquido/liquido-mobile-pwa-vue3_3/src/services/router.js. Does the file exist?
```

The file `/Users/doogie/Coding/liquido/liquido-mobile-pwa-vue3_3/src/views/welcome-chat` does exist. But with .vue extension. Is that a problem in vite?

Comment: oh, ups, could it be that this is really by design. Do I HAVE TO include the  .vue extension in all my imports???? Kinda uncommon....  https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/178

Comment: The omitted .vue extension can cause problems in some setups, not only Vite. Keeping it will cause less problems. The whole .vue thing isn't spec-compliant and so is quirky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the `extensions` property in the `resolve` part of your `vite.config.js` to add `vue` extension

See [here](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#resolve-extensions) (default is `['.mjs', '.js', '.mts', '.ts', '.jsx', '.tsx', '.json']`)

Your vite config should look like

```js
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.mjs', '.js', '.ts', '.jsx', '.tsx', '.json', '.vue'],
    alias: {
      // This SHOULD resolve my imports, but it seems to have a problem
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))    
    }
  }
})
```